# how to load your own file into a lein repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am reading a Clojure book. I typed one of the examples into a file. How can I load it into a `lein repl`?

I don't have a `lein` project and would prefer not to create one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`lein repl` (this will not create a lein project)

then in repl

`user=> (load-file "yourfile.clj")`

Comment: after the source file is updated, `load-file` will also reload the updates.